# Implementing method add for an ArrayList of 2D points(int,int)

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to create the method .add(int,int) for and ArraYList of the following data structure:

```
    class CPoint {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

in order to use it in the following way:

```
    ArrayList<CPoint> ar = new ArrayList<CPoint>();
    ar.add(100,100);
```

I know I have to start with something like this:

```
class CArrayListPoints extends ArrayList<CPoint>{
}
```

but not sure how. Please help me in this matter. 
EDIT: implement <-- extends

Comment: You cannot add new methods to existing classes.

Comment: you want to `extends` ArrayList<CPoint>, not `implements` it.

Comment: ArrayList is not an interface, you can't implement it.. you can only extend

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I believe OP is aware of that, hence the subclass of `ArrayList<CPoint>`.

Comment: @Vulcan: Sure, but then look at the second code snippet...

Comment: Thank you guys, replaced implements with extends

Comment: Is not a good idea to extend ArrayList only for typing less characters when adding objects. Is so much trouble to write ar.add(new CPoint(x, y);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class like this:

```
class CArrayListPoints extends ArrayList<CPoint>{

   public void add(int x, int y){
      super.add(new CPoint(x, y);
    }

}
```

Use this way:

```
CArrayListPoints list = new CArrayListPoint();
list.add(10, 10);
```

Comment: Class name is CPoint, Point has to be replaced with CPoint?

Comment: yes, i just updated it in the code example, also you need to have a CPoint constructor to receive the x, y by parameter like this: public CPoint(int x, int y){this.x=x; this.y=y;}

Comment: Was trying to use it like this:   ArrayList<CPoint> ar = new CArrayListPoints<CPoint>();
      ar.add(4,5); // won't work!

Comment: no, because the ArrayList<CPoint> doesn't have the add(int x, int y) method.. you would need to cast it

Answer (score 1):

Probably You are looking something like this

```
class CPoint {
        int x;
        int y;
    }

class CArrayListPoints extends ArrayList<CPoint>{
        public void add(int x, int y){
            CPoint p = new CPoint();
            p.x = x;
            p.y = y;

            add(p);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list with two values HashMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html is what you need. If you insist on using Arraylist, just make a add(int a,int b)method and have each CPoint have a field that contains the x value.

Comment: ... You're missing the point of what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: ArrayList is not made for 2 values per entry